# How can I catch event after configureMessageConverters?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using spring boot 1.2.5 and added `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` to get the object from the JSON request.

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mj2hmsc = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    mj2hmsc.setObjectMapper(new ScalaObjectMapper());

    converters.add(mj2hmsc);

}
```

But I want to add some values to the returned object. Where can I add some logic after this task is done? I think they provide the interface method like the followings.

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 * <p>This implementation is empty.
 */
@Override
public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
}
```

But I think it have parameter `List` of `HttpMessageConverter`. I think it isn't the proper to my expectation. Help me.

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: @M.Deinum Right after it returns the object, I want to set some values to it.

Comment: Returns which object? If you want to configure the converter or mapper just do it in that method... I don;t see the problem..